# 2x dynamic casting in one C++ line

Tags: c++

I have following line of `Qt/C++` code:

```
dynamic_cast<UeCentralWidget*>(this->centralWidget())->ueConnectedClientsTableView()->dynamic_cast<UeConnectedClientsTableModel*>(model())->ueConnectedClientData().append(new UeConnectedClientRecord(incomingData[2].toString(),
    incomingData[0].toString(),
    incomingData[1].toString()));
```

and it gives me error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'dynamic_cast'
```

How do I embedded second `dynamic_cast` into single line?

Comment: Why would you think that this were advisable? If you need a `dynamic_cast` with pointer type, without checking for it's return value, you are setting yourself up for undefined behavior (dereferencing a `nullptr`).

Comment: Why do you want to write this statement as a single line? Can you workaround the error by splitting it into several statements?

Comment: What's the fascination in doing this all on one line?  What's wrong with simply breaking this up into two lines?

Comment: I don't know what `someObjectOrPtr->someOtherPtr` could mean.

Comment: Simply don't. That huge chain of `->` and `.` sacrifices readability for... what?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, your second cast produces a pointer but you are using it as a method name.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling I'v seen mistake, thanks. I am a little bit tired ...

Comment: @KernelPanic: No, no no no, you are completely missing your mistake. You are using a `dynamic_cast` with pointer type. That will either return a valid pointer or `nullptr`. You are then dereferencing that pointer, without checking. This will break. What's the rationale for using a `dynamic_cast` with pointer type, without checking it's return value? What's the rationale for doing it **twice**? And asking how to do it on a single line, for crying out loud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic_cast<UeConnectedClientsTableModel*>(dynamic_cast<UeCentralWidget*>(this->centralWidget())->ueConnectedClientsTableView()->model())->ueConnectedClientData().append(new UeConnectedClientRecord(incomingData[2].toString(),
incomingData[0].toString(),
incomingData[1].toString()));
```

But I would add a `ueModel()` method to `ueConnectedClientsTableView` instead to be able to skip the second cast.

Comment: Ok, but it seems I totaly missed the point here, will post another question, this statement is really fishy ...